# Counter variable passed to `msgpack_pack_int()` macro doesn't increment

Tags: c, zeromq, msgpack

I have a very odd issue trying to run this quite simple [C program](https://gist.github.com/1222271/0f8d8d3f9ce4efcf797baf9c427d06e6c3dfd7ad) which is using *zmq* and *msgpack*.

There is no problem with `server.c`, however in `clinet.c:39` there
is this `msgpack_pack_int (&mpkg, i);` and the value of *`i`* seems
to be picked up as `0` and doesn't change on each iteration. I
have tried a bunch of different things (e.g. making a pointer to
*`i`* and using that, also tried to split it into a function etc)
and nothing seems to help. I can see that `msgpack_pack_int()` is
a macro, but why it would introduce such a behaviour and what can
I do to overcome it? Is there a flag that could change the behaviour
of this kind of macro (as I see it expands to an inline function)...
I have tried `-Werror -Wall`, with `gcc` and `clang`, and nothing
comes up in warning either ;(*

I tried debugging it and *`i`* increments as expected.

I even tried this, and it would do the same thing anyway:

```
void pack (msgpack_packer *p, msgpack_sbuffer *b) {

   static volatile int i = 0;

   printf("\ni=%d\n", i);
   msgpack_packer_init (p, b, msgpack_sbuffer_write);
   msgpack_pack_array (p, 2);
   msgpack_pack_int (p, i++);
   msgpack_pack_str (p, "/i/am/a/clinet/");

}
```

I have even tried something which was supposed to be different, but no luck here either -

```
int count (void) {
    static int i = 0;
    i += 1; return i;
}
```

can anyone see why would this happen?

*Update 1:* Also I have recompiled *msgpack*  library itself without optimization flags,
and that didn't change the behaviour either.

*Update 2:* Installed msgpack from the git repo and I get still have the same issue.

Comment: valgrind also doesn't quite help either - https://gist.github.com/1222962

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that on each iteration I was doing this:

```
 msgpack_packer_init (&mpkg, &sbuf, msgpack_sbuffer_write);
```

that needs to be done only once, and this should be there instead:

```
 msgpack_sbuffer_init (&sbuf);
```

or:

```
 msgpack_sbuffer_clear (&sbuf);
```

It was rather logical to put `msg_pack*` functions together and indeed
that was taken from the [simple example](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/blob/master/example/simple.c) and
the problem is really with the documentation, one extra comment would help!

*Update: [working version](https://gist.github.com/1222271/e5a1281df6a71f7286866940a7800606894a1662) & [version without memcpy](https://gist.github.com/1224142).*